# using the time function for srand in pseudo-random number generator in c

Tags: c, random, srand

```
#include <time.h>
((unsigned)time(NULL));
```

I don't understand why you have to include the time header file and use the time function in your program when creating a pseudo-random number generator using the function srand(). Can somebody please explain what the significance of time is in this case?

*** Please note that the code shown is only part of the program. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes the code non-repeatable when it is called for a second time.  If you include no seed or a fixed number for a seed, the program will act exactly the same, because the random number will be the same.

Answer (score 4):

It's because of the *Pseudo-* part of *Pseudorandom*. The PRNG performs a mathematical operation upon an internally-stored *seed* value to yield the next output number and transform the seed.

If you don't call `time(NULL)` or some other source of entropy (eg. `/dev/rand`), then the sequence will still be *pseudo-random* (not easily predictable by examining the values), but it will be exactly the same for every run of the program. Because, even though it may be very difficult to accurately predict the next number, it *is* possible because the PRNG is *deterministic*.

If you don't provide your own seed with `srand()`, the default initial seed is usually *1*.

The `time()` call provides the *initial source of entropy* that makes the starting seed unpredictable.

Comment: The deterministic part is actually very useful. I wrote a program to [draw a picture of random trees](http://code.google.com/p/xpost/downloads/detail?name=pastelforests.ps) and since it prints the seed value for each image, the same picture can be re-generated by re-using the same seed (unless changes to the program change its use of `rand` or the number of calls to `rand`, as these will alter the pattern of number flowing through the program). Particularly to debug a *bad* run, being able to re-start the same sequence is really, really useful.